# pass and use icon from another app in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

inside a cordova plugin I am grabbing the icon from an app. That works as you can find it in different places on stackoverflow.
But now I need to pass the icon as a graphic back to the javascript frontend and display it.

So far I tried a Base64 encoded png, but it did not work (as I could easily put the base64 image innside an url() and show it as background image).

Any idea how would be the best way to pass it into javascript?

So far I have:

```
BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) icon);
Bitmap bitmap = bitDw.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapByte = stream.toByteArray();

appIcon = new String(bitmapByte);
```

I can pass back appIcon, but cannot display it as an image.